# Getting xmonad and gnome-panel working with Fedora 18

Tags: fedora, gnome3

I have been using fedora 18 lately and trying to get xmonad working with gnome-panel.  On my ubuntu and kali installations this works perfectly fine, but in fedora I have yet to get gnome-panels to show up correctly.  Any help as to why the gnome-panels show up the way they do and getting it to work correctly is greatly appreciated.  Here is a screenshot.  Notice the 2 black panels on the right.  I have figured out they are suppose to be the upper and lower gnome-panel menus but obviously they are not working in fedora and xmonad yet.[image]

I have an xmonad desktop file

```
#/usr/share/applications/xmonad.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Xmonad
Exec=xmonad-start
NoDisplay=true
X-GNOME-WMName=Xmonad
X-GNOME-Autostart-Phase=WindowManager
X-GNOME-Provides=windowmanager
X-GNOME-Autostart-Notify=false
```

I have a gnome-session file

```
#/usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/xmonad.session
[GNOME Session]
Name=Xmonad/GNOME
RequiredComponents=gnome-settings-daemon;gnome-panel;
RequiredProviders=windowmanager;notifications;
DefaultProvider-windowmanager=xmonad
DefaultProvider-notifications=notification-daemon
```

I have an xsessions file

```
#/usr/share/xsessions/xmonad.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=XMonad Gnome
Comment=Lightweight tiling window manager
TryExec=/usr/bin/gnome-session
Exec=gnome-session --session=xmonad
#Icon=xmonad.png
Type=XSession
```

This works just fine in my other systems but in fedora after logging into xmonad gnome-panel seems to open two panels that are suppose to be the gnome-panels at the top and the bottom but they are blank.  Plus you can't close them or anything else with them.

Inside my xmonad.hs file a the top I import the GnomeConfig module and the ManageDocks module.

```
import XMonad.Config.Gnome
import XMonad.Hooks.ManageDocks
```

I also have added gnome-panel ignore to my configuration, but I don't know for all certainty what it does ( I just know it made my other systems work after adding it)

```
myManageHook = composeAll
[ manageHook gnomeConfig
, className =? "File Operation Progress"  --> doFloat
, className =? "google-chrome"  --> doShift "4:chrome"
, resource  =? "desktop_window" --> doIgnore
, resource  =? "kdesktop"       --> doIgnore
, resource  =? "gnome-panel"    --> doIgnore ]
```

And I have changed my defaults to the GnomeConfig that I imported at the top.

```
main = xmonad defaults

defaults = gnomeConfig {

  -- simple stuff
    terminal           = myTerminal,
    focusFollowsMouse  = myFocusFollowsMouse,
    borderWidth        = myBorderWidth,
    modMask            = myModMask,
    -- numlockMask deprecated in 0.9.1
    -- numlockMask        = myNumlockMask,
    workspaces         = myWorkspaces,
    normalBorderColor  = myNormalBorderColor,
    focusedBorderColor = myFocusedBorderColor,

  -- key bindings
    keys               = myKeys,
    mouseBindings      = myMouseBindings,

  -- hooks, layouts
    layoutHook         = myLayout,
    manageHook         = myManageHook,
    handleEventHook    = myEventHook,
    logHook            = myLogHook,
    startupHook        = myStartupHook
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I will have to investigate some more but things are working now with the same config that I have posted above.  The only difference now is that I am using a new xmonad.hs file for fedora but with the same Gnome.Config stuff.  Here is a screenshot Im just posting this to help with anyone else searching for these answers.  [image]

Answer (score 0):

I've been using xMonad and Gnome for a couple of years now.  F16, F17, and now F18.   But there is an ongoing nasty issues with the Gnome menus not drawing properly on anything other than the first page of the pager screens.  Its been reported a few places but no solutions so far that I have found.

Comment: Could you add the links that you're referencing which mention these reports? Might be helpful for others that may come across your answer in the future.

Comment: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=141573 but I was unable to get his "fixes" to work for m